# Simple JSON file to SQL Server table in Python or T-SQL (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: python, json, t-sql, sql-server-2014, arcgis

I've got some JSON files that I need to upload to our SQL Server as tables. A Python script would be ideal (as I'm using ArcGIS Pro and Python to generate the JSON files) but T-SQL would also be okay.

Unfortunately I'm using SQL Server 2014 so things like OpenJSON (which came in on 2016) can't be used.

Does anyone know of a good script or example (if, say, the file is on the server at c:\MyFiles\MyJSON.json)?

Comment: You use Python to generate JSON and then want to store this JSON as SQL Server table? A bit weird for me :) Maybe it is better to provide data in table format in SQL Server instead of using JSON?

Comment: Alas, we are obtaining data using REST first of all.